# With or without "for"?

Tags: prepositions, for

> I have ordered for a cup of tea

Or

> I have ordered a cup of tea

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Dictionaries with examples would answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You order something for someone or something. You don't order for something for someone or something in English. That doesn't sound idiomatic. For example:

> I ordered a cup of tea for you.
>
> I ordered a printer and twenty reams of A4 paper for the office.

*I ordered for a cup of tea* sounds like you placed an order for a cup of tea as though it were a living thing that was interested in receiving something from you, which is really just pure nonsense.

However, note that if the word *order* is used as a noun, then you most certainly can use it with the preposition *for*:

> We received an order for a cup of tea.
>
> I placed an order for a printer and twenty reams of A4 paper.

Comment: To **revive** an order is a legalism, where **order** is a kind of legal decree by a judge or a parliamentary body.  It is not used when placing orders for food and drink or other consumable goods.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write *received*. My bad.

Comment: Too bad it was a typo.  Reviving an order for a cup of tea has a sort of *Alice-in-Wonderland* quality :)

Comment: The very first thing that came to my mind when I read this question was, "I **rang** ***for*** a cup of tea." ;)